# WCF Ajax service - catch all requests to a single service for token based API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have one ajax enabled WCF service that handles third party user requests. There is about dozens of methods within the service class. The request structure of each method is a JSON and has two "sub-objects" - Header and Attributes. Header is the same for all methods. Attributes can have different structure (depending on each method needs).

Like so:

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        public JSONResponseGetList GetList(JSONRequestGetList data)
        {
            //check if the data.header.securityToken is valid
        }
    ..
  ..
```

Here is the **JSONRequestGetList**:

```
public class JSONRequestGetList 
{
    public class AttributesClass 
    {
        public Int64 timeStamp { get; set; }
        public int maxCount { get; set; }
    }

    public ModelRequestHeader header { get; set; }
    public AttributesClass attributes{ get; set; }
}
```

..and here is **ModelRequestHeader** which is the same for all types of requests:

```
public class ModelRequestHeader
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string securityToken { get; set; }
}
```

**Now my question** - I have a repeated code in every method that checks if the *securityToken* is valid or not. The same "IF" in every method. Is there a way to somehow intercept the "Header" structure of every request made to my "Service" class on a single place and perhaps decorate somehow my methods (for example something similar like [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] in WebAPI) so it automatically steps inside the method or returns 401 Unauthorized?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface which contains a method called [BeforeCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.beforecall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Called before client calls are sent and after service responses are returned.

It takes over the operation name and the inputs that the client passed to it, in the form of an object array.